# Get request: multiple header options with same key?

Tags: .net, api, rest, authorization, restsharp

i am working with API, which expects the header like this:

> Authorization: ClientKey keyhere
>   Authorization: UserKey key2here

when i am adding this params to RestSharp's request like this:

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "ClientKey 111111");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "UserKey 222222");
```

i see, that only last one is written.
It's because of they have the same key.
But how can i avoid it?

I understand, that it is wrong behavior on the server side, but this code is already using in production for other platforms.

**Updated**

I found solution:

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "ClientKey 111111, UserKey 222222");
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to replace `keyhere` with your key?

Comment: you are right! but it does not solve my problem

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have two headers with the same name. They work as a key/value pair, and therefore duplicates can't exist. What API are you working with?

Comment: nda. This api works ok through Rest Client / Postman extensions of Chrome with multiple rows Authorization, as i wrote. That's why i am trying to get the same possibilities in .net.

Comment: @OlegKalyta Your solution was to fix the client, right?

Answer (score 3):

See section [14.8 Authorization](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) of the HTTP RFC:

> A user agent that wishes to authenticate itself with a server--
>         usually, but not necessarily, after receiving a 401 response--does
>         so by including an Authorization request-header field with the
>         request.

See also section [3.2.2 The Authorization Request Header](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) of RFC 2617:

> The client is expected to retry the request, passing an Authorization
>      header line, which is defined according to the framework above,
>      utilized as follows.

Both quotes talk about **an** and **the** header. According to the RFC it *may* be possible to set the `Authentication` header multiple times. But the server will have no way to pick the *one* header that contains the credentials according to the RFC.

The *server* is working correct by using only one (the last such header). Your *client* is broken.

Comment: i decided to check, what Rest Client exactly send to server:
Authentication: key1 value1, key2 value2

i did the same and it's worked for me